# Kingfisher XCode 15 & iOS 17 Support

Tags: kingfisher

I just upgraded my XCode to version 15.
When I try to return Provider with computed property, it gave me the error below;

`Argument type 'ImageResource' does not conform to expected type 'Resource'`

Is there any possibility that you update library compatible with new versions.

Regards.

Just update the pod, provider is now not valid.

Comment: I've found the solution but forget to mention, you can user Kingfisher.ImageResource because its now used by Apple as well, regards.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to replace "ImageResource" with "Kingfisher.ImageResource" wherever the editor says you have an error. No need to do anything else, it should now build as it did before the Xcode update.

Comment: Hey, can you provide some further information about how to use Kingfisher.ImageResource?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere no problem - I am assuming you are having the issue where your target won't build because of ImageResource as mentioned in the question.  You just need to replace "ImageResource" with "Kingfisher.ImageResource" wherever the editor says you have an error.  No need to do anything else, it should now build as it did before the Xcode update.

Comment: Thanks for that information, I was reviewing your answer as it was flagged by the system for being very short and I have updated your answer accordingly. Feel free to edit any additional information to your answer such as explaining why it works.

Comment: Outstanding ....

Answer (score 2):

Use Kingfisher.ImageResource as a temporary fix.

ImageResource(name: <#T##String#>, bundle: <#T##Bundle#>)this is creating conflict with KingFisher's ImageResource(downloadURL:URL) method in xcode 15 after updating.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes "Xcode 15 release notes" Visit asset catalog section.